# Transaction support in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, transactions, ejb, vert.x

Is there any transaction support in nodejs similar to EJB for java. I don't seem to find any. Most of the posts suggest using EJB's in addition to nodejs.

Would vert.x be better in such a situation. I need to set up a payment gateway on an asynchronous model. Wondering whether to go for vert.x or nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ORM for Node.js that has support for transaction like [Sequelize.js](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/). Although there are some limitation but can support a simple implementation.

Here is a sample code from [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/transactions/)

```
 return sequelize.transaction().then(function (t) {
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'Homer',
    lastName: 'Simpson'
  }, {transaction: t}).then(function (user) {
    return user.addSibling({
      firstName: 'Lisa',
      lastName: 'Simpson'
    }, {transaction: t});
  }).then(function () {
    t.commit();
  }).catch(function (err) {
    t.rollback();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Wangot pointed out, there are transactions in various Node.js packages, and `sequelize` is a great package because it can connect to various SQL-based databases.

If you use `sequelize`, and if you come from a java background, then also take a look at the [`zb-sequelize`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zb-sequelize) npm package. It simplifies transaction management extremely by adding 2 decorators: `@Transactional` and `@Tx`

```
import { Transactional, Tx } from 'zb-sequelize';

@Transactional
function fooBar(@Tx transaction) {
  foo(transaction);
  bar(transaction);
}

@Transactional
function foo(@Tx transaction) {
}

@Transactional
function bar(@Tx transaction) {
}
```

If you've worked with Spring before, then this will probably look familiar.